# How to group a list of objects into a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of:

```
public class Item
{
   public int FirstId { get; set; }
   public int SecondId { get; set; }
   public int Sequence { get; set; }
}
```

A sample list might be:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
list.Add( new Item{ FirstId = 1, SecondId = 10, Sequence = 1 } );
list.Add( new Item{ FirstId = 2, SecondId = 10, Sequence = 1 } );
list.Add( new Item{ FirstId = 2, SecondId = 11, Sequence = 2 } );
list.Add( new Item{ FirstId = 3, SecondId = 10, Sequence = 1 } );
list.Add( new Item{ FirstId = 4, SecondId = 10, Sequence = 2 } );
list.Add( new Item{ FirstId = 4, SecondId = 11, Sequence = 1 } );
```

I need to group the items by FirstId and sort each group by Sequence. The result should be:

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>();
```

where the key is FirstId, and value is the list of SecondId ordered by Sequence. So the result of the above should be:

```
Key (int), Value (IEnumerable<int>)
1, (10)
2, (10, 11)
3, (10)
4, (11, 10)
```

Currently I have the following:

```
var items = from t in tags
            group t by t.FirstId into g
            orderby g.Key
            select g;
```

How can I expand on the above to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use method `ToDictionary`. Try this code:

```
tags
  .GroupBy(t => t.FirstId)
  .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, g => g.OrderBy(t => t.Sequence).Select(t => t.SecondId));
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kbq7eR)